# SQL: Join 2 tables and get only one result per condition from the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I have the following tables:

Auction-table

```
Id | Title | Description 
------------------------
1  | Test1 | DescriptionForTest1
2  | Test2 | DescriptionForTest2
3  | Test3 | DescriptionForTest3
```

and

Bids-Table

```
AuctionId | UserId | Bidding
----------------------------
1         | 2      | 10
1         | 32     | 24
1         | 2      | 30
1         | 46     | 50
2         | 13     | 5
2         | 20     | 10
and so on...
```

Now I want a output, similar to this

```
AuctionId | Title | Description | UserId
----------------------------------------
1         | Test1 | Desc...     | 46
2         | Test2 | Desc...     | 20
```

I need one row per auction with the UserId with the highest Bidding.

I know that I could do this with 2 SQL-Statements. First getting all auctions and second with MAX(Bidding). But I need this in one statement and I'm stucking to get a working SQL-Statement.

Could anyone help me please?

I'm using MySQL as DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS auction;
CREATE TABLE auction
(auction_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Title VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,Description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO auction VALUES
(1  ,'Test1','DescriptionForTest1'),
(2  ,'Test2','DescriptionForTest2'),
(3  ,'Test3','DescriptionForTest3');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bids;
CREATE TABLE bids
(auction_id INT NOT NULL 
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,bid INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (auction_id,user_id,bid)
);

INSERT INTO bids VALUES
(1         ,2      ,10),
(1         ,32     ,24),
(1         ,2      ,30),
(1         ,46     ,50),
(2         ,13     ,5),
(2         ,20     ,10);

SELECT a.*
     , b.user_id
     , b.bid 
  FROM auction a 
  JOIN bids b
    ON b.auction_id = a.auction_id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT auction_id, MAX(bid) max_bid FROM bids GROUP BY auction_id) c 
    ON c.auction_id = b.auction_id 
   AND c.max_bid = b.bid;
+------------+-------+---------------------+---------+-----+
| auction_id | Title | Description         | user_id | bid |
+------------+-------+---------------------+---------+-----+
|          1 | Test1 | DescriptionForTest1 |      46 |  50 |
|          2 | Test2 | DescriptionForTest2 |      20 |  10 |
+------------+-------+---------------------+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Strawberry's answer is one way. Here is a second way. Try them both and see which one is faster on your setup. Indexes and table sizes will make a big difference.

```
SELECT High_Bid.AuctionId, A.Title, A.Description, High_Bid.UserID FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM bids_table
        ORDER BY AuctionId, Bidding DESC
    ) AS B1
    GROUP BY AuctionId
) AS High_Bid
JOIN
auction_table AS A
ON High_Bid.AuctionId=A.Id
```

Comment: Note that this method is undocumented (unless you count the `comments` section of the relevant page of the manual), and relies on, in effect, an idiosyncrasy of MySQL's design. That said, the same could be said of other popular 'hacks' and isn't a reason to disregard the solution outright. But it's unlikely to perform significantly faster than the 'documented' solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97fc0e/7/0)**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
SELECT a.Id AS AuctionId,
       a.Title,
       a.Description,
       (SELECT b.UserId 
        FROM Bids b
        WHERE b.AuctionId  = a.Id
        ORDER BY b.Bidding DESC
        LIMIT 1) as UserId
FROM Auction a) t
WHERE T.UserID is not null
```

Result:

```
| AUCTIONID | TITLE |         DESCRIPTION | USERID |
----------------------------------------------------
|         1 | Test1 | DescriptionForTest1 |     46 |
|         2 | Test2 | DescriptionForTest2 |     20 |
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with this sql:

```
select ID, Title, Description, UserId from Auction a 
right join Bids b on a.ID = b.AuctionId
right join (select AuctionId, max(Bidding) as Bidding from Bids group by AuctionId) c on b.AuctionId = c.AuctionId and b.Bidding = c.Bidding;
```

Fiddle is here: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa006/1)

Result with a third user:

```
ID  TITLE   DESCRIPTION             USERID
1   Test1   DescriptionForTest1     46
2   Test2   DescriptionForTest2     20
3   Test3   DescriptionForTest3     23
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(BINDING),A.AUCTION_ID,A.DESCRIPTION,A.TITLE,B.USER_ID 
FROM AUCTION_TABLE A,BIDS_TABLE B
WHERE A.AUCTION_ID=B.AUCTION_ID
```

OR TRY WITH JOINS

```
SELECT MAX(BINDING),A.AUCTION_ID,A.DESCRIPTION,A.TITLE,B.USER_ID 
FROM AUCTION_TABLE A
INNER JOIN BIDS_TABLE B ON A.AUCTION_ID=B.AUCTION_ID
```